# How can I replace spaces in a JSON object keys dynamically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

How can I replace the spaces in a JSON object's keys *dynamically*? For example, if I have the following object:

```
[{
    "FIRST NAME": "Philip",
    "LAST NAME": "Rivers",
    "NUMBER": "17",
    "GPA": "1.0",
    "OLD_FACTOR": "8",
    "NICENESS": "1"
}, {
    "FIRST NAME": "Peyton",
    "LAST NAME": "Manning",
    "NUMBER": "18",
    "GPA": "4.0",
    "OLD_FACTOR": "5000",
    "NICENESS": "5000"
}]
```

I want to be able to dynamically rename "FIRST NAME" and "LAST NAME" to "FIRST_NAME" and "LAST_NAME" respectively. Based on research so far, I have this function:

```
function replaceSpaces(data) {
    debugger;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];
        for (var key in obj) {
            var replacedKey = key.split(' ').join('_');
            data[i][obj] = replacedKey;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

The "data" parameter being passed in is an object that has already had JSON.parse ran on it prior to entering this function.

My issue with this code is that it's looping through the keys just fine, and assigning the proper replaced string to "replacedKey", but it's not assigning that to the original data object.

Comment: `data[i][replacedKey] = data[i][key];`

Comment: Are you actually asking about JSON? That is, are you interested in transforming the text content of a JSON document/string, or are you merely interested in working with JavaScript objects?

Comment: I'm interested in modifying the key name of the JavaScript object (if I'm understanding you correctly). I've already parsed it into the object, so I'm not interested in changing the string prior to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's complete code using `forEach`.

The steps are same as [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) has stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33438900/2025923)

1. Copy the value
2. Remove the key-value from the object
3. Add new item with new value in the object

```js
var arr = [{
  "FIRST NAME": "Philip",
  "LAST NAME": "Rivers",
  "NUMBER": "17",
  "GPA": "1.0",
  "OLD_FACTOR": "8",
  "NICENESS": "1"
}, {
  "FIRST NAME": "Peyton",
  "LAST NAME": "Manning",
  "NUMBER": "18",
  "GPA": "4.0",
  "OLD_FACTOR": "5000",
  "NICENESS": "5000"
}];


// Iterate over array
arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
  // Iterate over the keys of object
  Object.keys(e).forEach(function(key) {
    
    // Copy the value
    var val = e[key],
      newKey = key.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
    
    // Remove key-value from object
    delete arr[i][key];

    // Add value with new key
    arr[i][newKey] = val;
  });
});

console.log(arr);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

---

**Strictly if the JSON is get in the form of String from server:**

Replace the spaces by `_` from the keys.

```
JSON.parse(jsonString.replace(/"([\w\s]+)":/g, function (m) {
    return m.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
}));
```

Comment: Ok I think I understand you guys now. One sec and I'll try to fit it into mine. (I was trying to avoid the .forEach function due to performance concerns).

Comment: @xboxremote Avoiding `forEach`? You should avoid `for...in` for better performance

Comment: My colleague mentioned he had found some articles saying .forEach performs slower. However, in researching myself, it does look like that might be false due to confusion in testing. At any rate, this worked perfectly (and I ended up using the .forEach). Thank you!

Comment: @Tushar thats some interesting information, I didn't know the for...in loop was that slow. (Found this test: https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/75)

Comment: @DownVoter, at-least consider adding comment when down-voting a **working** and **accepted** answer. I'd be happy to improve answer.

Comment: Well, in my script here, performance doesn't appear to be an issue at all. Iterating over the array and the keys only took a split-second. I may have to reevaluate if I get some bigger objects (since this is done dynamically).

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread user2415266's comment. But yeah, something to keep in mind I guess on for each vs for.

Comment: you are changing the object's shape with every iteration. it is quite inefficient. you can get away with it with small object's though.

Comment: @Tushar, strictly speaking about objects - it will be much faster to create new object with new keys rather then adding new key and deleting old one from original object.

Answer (score 4):

You need to:

- Copy the **value**
- Delete the old property
- Modify the correct object. (`data[i][obj]` will convert `obj` to a string and try to use it as a property name).

Such:

```
    for (var original_property in obj) {
        var new_property = original_property.split(' ').join('_');
        obj[new_property] = obj[original_property];
        delete obj[original_property]
    }
```

Comment: Slight error here: key.split should be original_property.split.

Answer (score 0):

since it is `JSON` it is expected to come as string you could do it with a help of `Regex`.

```
var processedJson = yourJson.replace(/( +)(?=[(\w* *]*":)/g, "_");
var yourObj = JSON.parse(processedJson);
```

`/( +)(?=[(\w* *]*":)/g` will find all ocurances of  within `" ... ":` which is a key on every JSON object.

Comment: Can you use `.replace` on an _Object_?

Comment: Right, I think Tushar is right here. I could do this earlier in my logic before I parse the JSON, but it wouldn't make sense in the context of my app. At this point in the app, I don't believe this would work.

Comment: regex works only with strings. but as I said JSON comes as string. or you however can use `JSON.stringify()` on every object in JS anytime you want

Comment: @Tushar when your JSON comes as string (from ajax) using Regex is a valid method, I don't see any reason why would I avoid it.

Comment: I might have been unclear in my original question, but I was looking to avoid any manipulation of the string equivalent, because I'm already past that in my app's logic. This function was designed to take an object, and not a string. Stringifying and parsing again would be unnecessary if I already have an object I can loop through. I definitely understand your proposal though.